# how to operate on global variables in c++

Tags: c++, variables, global

I need help with global vars in C++. I am passing an empty argv array into a parse function and I am trying to fill it, however when I access argv back in main, argv[0] comes back empty no matter what I enter in. Please help.

```
static int argc;
static char* argv[100];

void parse(string str, int argc, char* argv[])
{
    argc = 0;
    char * cstr = new char [str.length()+1];
    strcpy (cstr, str.c_str());
    char * p = strtok (cstr," ");
    int i = 0;
    while (p!=0)
        {
            argc++;
            argv[i] = p;
            p = strtok(NULL," ");
            i++;
        }
    delete[] cstr;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    string theLine;

    while (true) 
        {
            cout << "myshell> ";
            getline(cin,theLine);
            cout << "Command was: " << theLine << endl;
            if ((theLine == "exit") || (cin.eof()) || (theLine == "quit"))
                exit(0); 

            parse(theLine, argc, argv);
            cout << "argv[0] " << argv[0] << "\n";

        }   
}
```

I am trying to assign character strings to argv inside the parser function but when I go to access it in MAIN, it comes out blank. How do I achieve what I am trying to do? It has to do with global variables but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: static objects are automatically initialized to zero. Why does `argv[0] == 0` surprise you?

Comment: Even without static, it is not working

Comment: What makes you think you need to use global variables for this ?

Comment: How else would I operate on argc and argv in parse and send them back to main without having parse return them?

Comment: But you are aware you use an OOP language? Programming in C++ C-style is like driving a rolls-royce on a parking lot only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're storing pointers into `cstr` in `argv`, but then you're deleting `cstr` at the end of the `parse()` function. Get rid of:

```
delete[] cstr;
```

Also, you should pass `argc` by reference. Otherwise, when you update it in the `parse()` function it won't update the caller's variable. So it should be:

```
void parse(string str, int &argc, char *argv[])
```

However, you also have a memory leak. You're creating a new `cstr` each time `parse` is called, but never deleting it. You should change the function to return `cstr`, and have the caller delete it when they're done with that parsed line.

```
char *parse(str str, int &argv, char *argv[]) {
    ...
    return cstr;
}
```

Then in your `main()` loop, do:

```
int main( void ) 
{
    string theLine;

    while (true) 
        {
            cout << "myshell> ";
            getline(cin,theLine);
            cout << "Command was: " << theLine << endl;
            if ((theLine == "exit") || (cin.eof()) || (theLine == "quit"))
                exit(0); 

            char *cstr = parse(theLine, argc, argv);
            cout << "argv[0] " << argv[0] << "\n";
            delete[] cstr;
        }   
}
```

Comment: Sooner or later, OP has to delete `cstr`, though,  and after returning from the function they'll have to do it through `argv[0]`;

Comment: I did remove cstr and now it works, the code I posted above was just some debugging code I wrote because my program worked on my mac but not in linux. I appreciate all the help

Comment: @user4581301 Good point. I've updated the answer to add returning the string, and deleting it in the caller.

Comment: Can't use `delete[] argv[0]`, because that won't be correct if the input line starts with spaces.

Comment: Good counter point. `delete[] argv[0]` is *literally* a spaced-out answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about how global and local variables of the same name interact.
Let me start by saying that there are two distinct objects each named `argc` and two distinct objects each named `argv`.

The first set are the global variables

```
static int argc;
static char* argv[100];
```

The second set are the parameters of your `parse` function

```
void parse(string str, int argc, char* argv[])
{
    argc = 0;
    ...
}
```

I've taken one line from `parse`. What that does is actually set the object in the `argc` parameter to 0. The object in the global `argc` is **not** set to 0 by this.

Let's rename some of the variables in the above snippet to see clearly which name belongs to which object/place:

```
static int global_argc;
static char* global_argv[100];

void parse(string str, int argc, char* argv[])
{
    argc = 0;
    ...
}
```

Now, notice how I changed the first two to `global_`, but the rest (all of the, even the ones not shown) remain `argc` and `argv`.

You need to start by learning about variable scope. Once arrays and pointers are involved, such as `argv`, things get even more complicated. I could not possibly explain all of this to you in one answer, except for: *first learn more about variables and variable scope. Then learn about pointers and arrays. Then come back to this program and see if you can fix it, which is not something you can do at this point in time.*
It may take a little more time, and a little more work, but don't get discouraged.

Comment: Agree with the sentiment, but that's not OP's problem.

Comment: @user4581301 It might not be the direct problem, but what good is just handing out code saying 'this fixes it' if the OP does not understand at all what he is doing? I think, looking further than the direct superficial question, that this is the answer.

Comment: Furthermore, it is actually the problem: OP doesn't understand how the parameters and global variables interract, and the fact that the pointer assignment to `argv` works is an unhappy coincidence.

Comment: Agree with that sentiment, too, but even sorting out the scoping, doesn't solve OP's problem. They could have implemented every one of your recommendations and had the same problem. The one variable affected by the bad scoping was not used, and the killer was the poorly-placed `delete`.